# How to install react-dom in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom

in my react native app I want to install react-dom.
when I tried to install with "npm i react-dom" then it's not installing .
So how can I install react-dom ?

Comment: you built the project by expo or bare react native? if expo, may try `expo npm i react-dom`. and sharing the error screenshot will be much better to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use react-dom in react-native apps. 'react-dom' is can only use in web applications. I don't know why you want use 'react-dom' in react-native but if you want you can create web app with react and use it as webview in react-native